# Writing and Loading inside the same textfile in Powershell

Tags: powershell

im currently programming an autosort script which is deleting duplicated SessionID's. For that i need to Read a textfile, then write into it and then Read it agian(With the new text in it ) ,all that in the same script.
I checked my code multiple times and it seems fine, but i cant get it to work. Is it possible that when using `Add-Content`, that Powershell only writes the information into the textfile after the script is done ? The script is kinda long but here is an example :

```
$path1 = "C\blabla"
$path2 = "C\blabla2"

$oldIDs = Get-Content $path1
$newIDs = Get-Content $path2

foreach($temp in $oldIDs){
 if($oldIDs != $newIDs){  <---(Not my actual code just there to make it simple)

    $oldIDs |Add-Content $newIDs
    $check = Get-Content $newIDs   <-----(Here i want to check if the new ID is in there and that is where it isnt working )
    

 }
}
```

Sorry if it isnt understandable very good, please ask if you are confused

Comment: If I got it right I think you should read the file **completely** treat it like you need and then write it back **completely**.  After that you can read it again ... **completely**

Comment: If you want to compare a file against another file you may take a look at the cmdlet `Compare-Object`.

Comment: `    $oldIDs |Add-Content $newIDs` this doesn't add content to the file.  This adds content to the **array** of `$oldIDs`.  I think this is possibly the source of your confusion.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Oh i did not know that, maybe `Out-File` is what i want?

Comment: PowerShell does not use traditional comparison evaluators, so `!=` will not work the way you expect.  The PowerShell equivalent for this command is `-ne`, for `not equals`

Comment: @FoxDeploy i know, thats why i wrote that it isnt my actual code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to fix is your comparison, which should be:

```
if ($oldIds -ne $newIds)
```

As PowerShell doesn't use the `=` character for value assignment.

I'll tweak your scenario to something I think is a bit more understandable, we'll read all the items from $oldIds, then check to see if it is in $newIds, if not, then we'll add the value.  Then at the end we'll save the file.

```
$path1 = "C:\temp\oldIDs.txt" #changed to match the variables for consistency
$path2 = "C:\temp\newIDs.txt"

$oldIDs = Get-Content $path1
$newIDs = Get-Content $path2

if ($newIDs -eq $null){$newIDs = @()}

foreach($thisID in $oldIDs){
 if($newIds -Contains $thisId){
    "skipping $thisId because it is already contained in `$newIds` "
  }
  else{ 
   "have not seen $thisId, so adding to newIds"
    #add this value to $newIds  
    $newIds += $thisId
 }
}

$newIDs.Count
#save $newId
$newIDs | set-content $path2
```

Then with an empty newIds.txt, and this body in oldIDs.txt

```
oldIds.txt
HAM
HAM
BEEF
HAM
CHICKEN
HAM
BEEF
HAM
CHICKEN
```

We get this output

```
have not seen HAM, so adding to newIds
skipping HAM because it is already contained in $newIds 
have not seen BEEF, so adding to newIds
skipping HAM because it is already contained in $newIds 
have not seen CHICKEN, so adding to newIds
skipping HAM because it is already contained in $newIds 
skipping BEEF because it is already contained in $newIds 
skipping HAM because it is already contained in $newIds 
skipping CHICKEN because it is already contained in $newIds
```

Hopefully this is understandable and gives you a framework you can extend for your purposes.